# WordPress External Cookie Authentication

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I create an authentication system for an external application (without using WordPress internal files) using the cookie stored by WordPress? A pointer on the working of WordPress Cookie Authentication would be helpful also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**wp-includes/user.php** is where authentication is handled. You might be particularly interested in looking at the function **wp_authenticate_cookie()** to get an understanding of how auth works ...

Also take a look at **[this article](http://willnorris.com/2009/03/authentication-in-wordpress-28)**, which covers wordpress authentication.